# SwiftUI iterating List not applying listRow modifiers

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I have created the following `List`

```swift
List {
 Text("Hello")
   .listRowBackground(Color.red)
}
```

Which renders this view:
[image]

When I change the `List` to iterate over a range, it stops applying the `listRow` modifier:

```swift
List (0 ..< 3) { _ in
  Text("Hello")
    .listRowBackground(Color.red)
}
```

[image]

Why is that happening?

Comment: Try this : List { ForEach { Text....

Comment: @RajaKishan Thanks - using the modifier with ForEach seems to be working! Still curious why `List` won't apply those modifiers

Comment: Don't know the main reason but you can check many modifiers that work with ForEach. Even apple doc using ForEach. Check this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/listrowbackground(_:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You required `ForEach`. As mention in [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/listrowbackground(_:))

> The SwiftUI ForEach structure computes views for each element of the enumeration and extracts the raw value of each of its elements using the resulting text to create each list row item. The listRowBackground(_:) modifier then places the view you supply behind each of the list row items:

So the final code is,

```
List {
    ForEach(0 ..< 3){  _ in
        Text("Hello")
            .listRowBackground(Color.red)
    }
}
```